# How can I force a child to have square dimensions in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Let's say I have a button in a stack layout that fills the parent horizontally. How do I make it so that it's vertical height is the same as the horizontal length? Preferably entirely in xaml, but in c# if it must.

Comment: Provide some code of your try, a screenshot of the desired result may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is by binding the height of the object to it's width

```
  Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in code like this in code:

```
button.SetBinding(VisualElement.HeightRequestProperty, new Binding() { Source = button, Path = "Width" });
```

Comment: That's nice but I don't understand the upvote. yawnobleix got the same in XAML which was requested.